# ARM clock speed on raspberry pi

Tags: embedded, arm, low-level, raspberry-pi

Running bare-metal (no operating system, no Linux)

The specs implies the ARM can/does run 700MHz, the sys clock matches the manual and appears to be running at 250MHz.  Simple tests on the ARM imply that it is doing the same, for example with the instruction cache on

```
test:
  subs r0,r0,#1
  bne test
```

And vary the number of subs instructions to dominate over the branch, it is in the ball park of 250MHz but a long way away from 700MHz.

I there a phy setting that I am not seeing in the datasheet for multiplying the ARM clock?

EDIT:

Maybe my assumptions are flawed...

```
.globl ARMTEST0
ARMTEST0:
    subs r0,r0,#1
    bne ARMTEST0
    bx lr

.globl ARMTEST1
ARMTEST1:
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    bne ARMTEST1
    bx lr

.globl ARMTEST2
ARMTEST2:
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    subs r0,r0,#1
    bne ARMTEST2
    bx lr

.globl ARMTEST3
ARMTEST3:
    subs r1,r0,#1
    subs r2,r1,#1
    subs r3,r2,#1
    subs r0,r3,#1
    subs r1,r0,#1
    subs r2,r1,#1
    subs r3,r2,#1
    subs r0,r3,#1
    subs r1,r0,#1
    subs r2,r1,#1
    subs r3,r2,#1
    subs r0,r3,#1
    subs r1,r0,#1
    subs r2,r1,#1
    subs r3,r2,#1
    subs r0,r3,#1
    bne ARMTEST3
    bx lr
```

System timer ticks in hex per function (250Mhz system timer verified against stopwatch, etc).

```
02DB6DF7 ARMTEST0
02DB6E1C ARMTEST0
00AB6E2A ARMTEST1
00836E46 ARMTEST2
00836E2A ARMTEST3
```

Which gives:

```
ARMTEST0
0x01000000 subs instructions
0x01000000 bne  instructions
0x02000000 instructions
1.43 clocks per instruction.  175Mips.

ARMTEST1
0x01000000 sub instructions
0x00200000 bne instructions
0x01200000 instructions
1.68 instructions per clock. 420Mips

ARMTEST2
0x01000000 sub instructions
0x00100000 bne instructions
0x01100000 instructions
2.07 instructions per clock. 517Mips

ARMTEST3
0x01000000 sub instructions
0x00100000 bne instructions
0x01100000 instructions
2.07 instructions per clock. 517Mips
```

The ARM11 is super-scalar more than one instruction per clock is not unexpected.  I would expect more though.  Using only register 0 might mess with the pipe as you have to wait for one result of one instruction before executing the next.  I was expecting to see a difference between test 2 and 3, perhaps another bad assumption.  Maybe its really 500Mhz not 700?  There is one line in the linux sources that mentions a 500000000 clock.

```
static struct clk osc_clk = {
#ifdef CONFIG_ARCH_BCM2708_CHIPIT
    .rate = 27000000,
#else
    .rate = 500000000,  /* ARM clock is set from the VideoCore booter */
#endif
};

/* warning - the USB needs a clock > 34MHz */

#ifdef CONFIG_MMC_BCM2708
static struct clk sdhost_clk = {
#ifdef CONFIG_ARCH_BCM2708_CHIPIT
    .rate = 4000000,    /* 4MHz */
#else
    .rate = 250000000,  /* 250MHz */
#endif
};
#endif
```

Maybe what I think I have measured as 250Mhz is 270 and the ARM is at 500MHz?

EDIT2...DOH

That wasnt a great pipeline improvement was it, this is better:

```
.globl ARMTEST3
ARMTEST3:
    subs r0,r0,#1
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    subs r0,r0,#1
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    subs r0,r0,#1
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    subs r0,r0,#1
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    subs r0,r0,#1
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    subs r0,r0,#1
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    subs r0,r0,#1
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    subs r0,r0,#1
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    nop
    bne ARMTEST3
    bx lr


    ARMTEST3
    0x01000000 sub instructions
    0x08000000 nop instructions
    0x00100000 bne instructions
    0x09100000 instructions
    037000D7 system clocks
    2.64 instructions per clock. 659Mips
```

I failed to get config.txt to work at first, then re-build a linux sd card, booted it to find that the /boot/ directory is in fact the fat partition that contains the gpu boot files and the kernel.img arm boot file.  So NOT in a boot/ dir but in that same dir with the .bin's and .elf and .img file create config.txt and put arm_freq=something, the gpu bootloader then makes the modification to the pll multiplier so that when the arm starts it is at that speed.  I still expect more than 700 million instructions per second and am not seeing that, will need to keep trying I guess.

Comment: You might perform a similar test under whatever is the most official  linux kernel for the pi (possibly hack the test into the kernel itself).  Also verify the number of instruction cycles required to execute your code.  And read through their device-specific kernel initialization code to see if they are reprogramming a pll register.

Comment: I am interested in knowing whether you booted your test code from the SD card or whether you JTAG'ed it in.  Not to assist with your question you understand, but because I am wondering whether you have found information on the bootloader.

Comment: There are three jtags, the gpu, the arm and the network chip.  GPU, no, I have not done anything with the gpu.  network jtag, nope, arm jtag, yes, can and have, but to use arm jtag you need arm code to switch gpio pins, which I use the sd card to boot that small program.  I have both a serial bootloader (arm starts on sd card) and jtag bootloader (arm starts on card).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be worth looking at the boot loader provided with the Arch Linux reference distribution from the Raspberry Pi organisation's download pages.  I have no idea whether it's a working option, but its config.txt includes the line

```
#arm_freq=800
```

There are also reports of people having overclocked the Pi - so information about initialising the clock is certainly out there, somewhere.

Comment: well, reading more about it this is exactly how it is supposed to work, but I cant get it to work...both my linux and fat file system have a /boot/config.txt file with different arm_freq=xxx numbers, and it doesnt change the speed of the arm.

Comment: A config file in /boot (or on some embedded linuxes, gzipped in /proc) tends to be a convenience *output* or note-to-later-administrators indicating the configuration with which the kernel was compiled.  Changing it post-compilation will have no effect.  Also, in such a file a leading '#' is a comment, disabling that line.  However, entries in such a file tend to be all caps beginning with CONFIG_ so you may have a different sort of file, though the output vs input possibility remains

Answer (score 2):

Probably due to the fact that the Raspberry Pi Foundation primarily comprises of Broadcom employees, they have chosen a Broadcom device as the CPU.  While this means that the RPi gets a relatively hi-performance ARM11 at very low cost, unfortunately Broadcom only provide full details of the chip to licencees, so the information you need to set up the PLL may not be publicly available, and I suspect is embedded in the "firmware" binaries provided by Broadcom.

Comment: There are indeed some unfortunate aspects to the release, but wouldn't the custom bare-metal system be downstream of the same proprietary initial bootloader as the suggested linux kernel and/or secondary bootloader?

Comment: my interest is in low level, bring up, not just writing an app on someone elses chip/board bring up.  the gpu is not changed here so far we dont have a way to mess with it.  if it had changed the pll then that would have been changed before the arm was released from reset which would affect me as well as the linux path.  if linux is actually running faster then the answer is likely in the linux sources, but was hoping someone knew the answer off hand.

Comment: of the many many boards I have brought up this is by far the nicest.  it has that huge broadcom wart on it though.  My hope is that this project might be the exception to the rule or demonstrate that it is not painful, in fact a good thing, to cooperate with the open source world.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about bare metal programming, but this code might be of use:
https://github.com/dwelch67/raspberrypi

Of note is the part of the readme that describes the boot order:

> 1) boots off of an on chip rom of some sort
>   2) reads the sd card and looks for additional gpu specific boot files
>   bootcode.bin, loader.bin, start.elf in the root dir of the first partition
>   (fat formatted)
>   3) in the same dir it looks for config.txt which you can do things like
>   change the arm speed from the default 700MHz, change the address where
>   to load kernel.img, and many others
>   4) it reads kernel.img the arm boot binary file and copies it to memory
>   5) releases reset on the arm such that it runs from the address where
>   the kernel.img data was written

Meaning that the config.txt is separate from the linux kernel and the chip sets the clockspeed itself (as long as this sequence is actually true.)

The code at that repository might help you answer your question.

Also, at the Raspberry Pi website, they did a post about official overclocking: http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/2008

They mention a cpufreq driver that you should be able to get the source to (since it's part of the linux source tree.) That might also help.

Answer (score 0):

You can tune your Raspberry Pi and change for example ARM clock speed and Ram/Video Ram. [A good tutorial](http://developer-blog.net/en/hardware-2/raspberry-pi-performance-tuning-2/).

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked and answered a while ago, but I ran across this question hoping to get a quick answer. In case anyone else might want to know this is how I fixed it for my bare-metal setup. I had success on the RPI3 by adding

> force_turbo=1
>   arm_freq=1200

Again, even though this was bare-metal, the config.txt is read by the GPU firmware before booting the ARM and loading your bare-metal code (from what I understand). I found this referenced [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/overclocking.md). Note that I also tried to programmatically change the frequency but couldn't find a reference (I even looked around the linux kernel source tree, but I'm a complete novice in kernel development).